# Cats and lactose intolerance

Tags: cats, diet

Lactose intolerance is a common issue among cats. Mostly in new born kittens, lactase (the enzyme required to digest lactose present in milk) is released in digestive tract. But as they grow older less and less lactase is released and the cats eventually become lactose intolerant. Moreover, even many kittens find it difficult to digest cow milk which has a higher proportion of lactose.

Now it not the same in all cats. In facts there are some cats, who even after becoming adults, love cow's milk, and will happily drink it if given.

On the other hand, there are some cats who leave even mother's milk at a young age.

Now, my question is,

1. Is cat's breed has got something to do with this?
2. Is the cat's geographical location got something to do with it?
3. Is it that some evolution has taken place after cats started to live with humans and 10,000 years backs none of the cats were able to digest lactose at an adult age?
4. Is it that some cats, simply don't like milk, but have the ability to digest lactose.